# display all data from my User table in my database

Tags: php, mysql

My question is how to display all data from my users table in my database?
I have this.

```
$loop = mysql_query(“SHOW users FROM $dbname”) or die (‘cannot select tables’);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');    
$result = mysql_query(“SELECT * FROM Users”, $link) or die (‘cannot select tables’);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to `SELECT` the users, not `SHOW` them.

Answer (score 1):

Basic SQL loop example:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    echo $row->id . ' ' . $row->nickname . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$loop = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `users`') or die();
```

You don't want your database name to be in the query, and you want to be using `SELECT`

If you haven't connected to the database earlier then you need to add this before your query:

```
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $user_password);
```